# Rescue as much data as possible from damaged tape

Tags: linux, data-recovery

We have some data on very old DDS (1,2 and 3) DAT tapes.
I tried reading them with:

```
dd if=/dev/st0 of=file bs=32k
```

but get many partial blocks and sometimes IO errors.
Have also tried with:

```
dd if=/dev/st0 of=file bs=32k conv=noerror
```

which does not stop at partial blocks but does sometimes give IO errors.
Some of these tapes contain tar archives but most of them contain a bunch of FITS files.
What would be the best way to rescue as much data as possible from these tapes?

Answer (score 7):

Send 'em to Kroll Ontrack (or another professional data recovery company). Your restore efforts are much more likely to further damage the tapes than doing anything productive.

Comment: To some degree I feel bad not voting for the answer that provided technical information, but the risk of additional loss due to half (or 3/4 or 7/8) measures, and not knowing how valuable the data is that is being recovered make me want to err on the side of caution.

Comment: I don't think the data is important enough to justify sending it to such a company. I would prefer to just read the maximum amount and spend a couple of hours regenerating the few files missing.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/s/ddrescue/ddrescue.html), which is written for exact this purpose. Depending on the importance of the data, a professional rescue service might be able to do much better, at a (likely very high) price.

Comment: ddrescue only works with block devices that allow non sequential access (am I right?). I thought it would not work with /dev/st0 which is a character device? If not I might give it a try.